# How do I extend (rather than override) an existing type declaration?

Tags: typescript, namespaces, typescript-typings

The type declarations for one of the libraries that I'm using are slightly outdated.  I'll report the issue upstream, but I'd like to work around the issue locally.  Unfortunately, when I add the missing declaration, TypeScript overrides the entire namespace, forgetting about all previous declarations.

**How do I add an extra function overload to an existing interface?**

My `tsconfig.json` looks like this (and I `npm install`ed `@types/codemirror`):

```
{ "compilerOptions": { "target": "es5", "module": "none",
                       "lib": ["es5", "dom"],
                       "strict": true },
  "files": ["test.ts"] }
```

My code (`test.ts`) looks like this:

```
namespace Test {
    export function test() {
        var host: HTMLElement = document.createElement("div");
        var editor: CodeMirror.Editor = CodeMirror(host);
        var oldText = editor.getValue();
        editor.setValue("", -1);
    }
}
```

Typescript rejects the last line (the codemirror.d.ts file doesn't know about the second argument).  Based on the "Declaration merging" section of the handbook, I add the following to the top of my file:

```
declare namespace CodeMirror {
    interface Editor {
        setValue(str: string, n: number): void;
    }
}
```

… which breaks everything: now TpeScript complains about `getValue` being unknown, and about CodeMirror being a namespace, not a function:

```
test.ts(10,45): error TS2708: Cannot use namespace 'CodeMirror' as a value.
test.ts(11,34): error TS2551: Property 'getValue' does not exist on type 'Editor'. Did you mean 'setValue'?
```

**How do I add the tell typescript about the missing overload of `setValue` without overriding the entire CodeMirror namespace?**

Comment: When you use CodeMirror(host), you are asking the compiler to consider the namespace to be a type.If you wish to invoke a member of the interface Editor then you need an implementing class of the interface. 1. Why do you require the namespace test and CodeMirror? 2. Can you do without the namespaces?

Comment: The library exports a top-level namespace; I don't require it, that's how it's designed; it's also both a namespace and a function.

Comment: Can you use the value "CommonJS" to tsconfig.json modules:? Share the screenshot of tsc output after the change to config.

Comment: @user2347763 It makes no change at all. I posted the output in the OP.

Comment: This - test.ts(10,45): error TS2708: Cannot use namespace 'CodeMirror' as a value. - 
is what I meant in my first comment. Although the docs say you use instantiating with =CodeMirror(host), since the api is not meant for nodejs, the module resolution path must have taken the nodejs route was my assumption but since you say that changing the modules: entry to commonJS doesn't change anything, you must give more info regarding your client. Are you using Browserify?

Comment: I'm not using Browserify, and I think that error is fairly clear: because of the overriding, Typescript things CodeMirror is only a namespace. But in the original definition (the original d.ts that's being overriden instead of updated), that line worked just fine.  See https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/codemirror/index.d.ts : it defines codemirror as both a namespace and a function.

Comment: Are you looking for an answer ? If you are, then the Github link clearly declares two methods with a comment that says these methods defineExtension and defineDocExtension should be used if you want to define extra methods to add to CodeMirror.

Comment: @user2347763 I'm definitely looking for an answer :) But I'm hoping for a more general one than one specific to CodeMirror.

Comment: What I mean is although you are looking for an answer, you don't seem to find one answering your specific general one :) Because there are lots of answers in the comments eg. a sto why the .d.ts is not being updated, why ts 'thinks' CodeMirror is a namespace because the right module is not getting wired etc.