# Cast type to only one property of a deconstructed object in Typescript

Tags: typescript, next.js

I have this `Next.js` method:

```
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async context => {

  const {query, locale, req} = context
  ...
}
```

Is there a way I can cast my own specific type to only the `query` parameter while deconstructing like so? Because by default each property in `query`...

```
const {prop1, prop2, prop3} = query
```

...has a default type of `string | string[]` which is somewhat too much to handle/override in code.

Comment: Will this work for you ? `const { prop1, prop2, prop3 } = query as Record<string, string>;`

Comment: or you want a global solution

Comment: I think you can redeclare the namepace you want to override using `declare namespace `

Comment: Not really... I have an interface for the named query parameters defined that I would like to use. Some parameters are strings, some are arrays, some are objects, etc.

Comment: Sorry, I replied before your last comment... How does declare namespace work? Never used it.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49699703/how-do-i-extend-rather-than-override-an-existing-type-declaration

Comment: check this instead https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12802383/extending-array-in-typescript

Comment: you can redeclare the same namespace again to override the defaults. I am not aware of NextJs TS declaration so don't know its type declarations

Comment: hm... but I don't want to extend the default type, I just want to override the type of the `query` parameter on the `context` object.

Comment: @captain-yossarian